# NetworkOnMain error with Retrofit and downloading an image

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have a problem where I get a `NetworkOnMainThread` error when I go to download users images. 
It crashes at the line that says:
`byte[] imgBytes = body.bytes();`
This is in the `onResponse` method in `RetroFit`. My understanding is that this method is not on the main thread. Or is that different from the UI thread?

Here's my code.

```
private void syncPersonPhoto(final DBHelper db, final ArrayList<Person> syncPersons, final int current) {
        final Person person = syncPersons.get(current);
        Call<ResponseBody> photoSyncCall = RestClient.get(context).getPersonPhoto(person.getPersonCode(), person.getPersonTypeCode());
        photoSyncCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    ResponseBody body = response.body();
                    try {
                        byte[] imgBytes = body.bytes(); <--- ERROR HERE
                        body.close();
                        String imgBase64 = Base64.encodeToString(imgBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                        db.addPersonImage(person.getPersonCode(), person.getPersonType(), imgBase64);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        log.log(TAG, "Bytes array couldn't be populated: " + e);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            }
        });
    }
```

Can anyone see a problem?

Thanks.

Comment: If it is saying you there is problem, why don't you try to run that line on a new thread?

Comment: Its says that the RetroFit::onResponse method is on the Main thread! I've used the `enqueue` method as can be seen. If I run it on another thread, then it'll be the same because Android only has 2 types of threads.

Comment: What do you think are those 2 types of threads?

Comment: The 2 types are Main/UI thread and background/worker threads. From what I understand, the `onResponse` method is done in the background/worker thread.

Comment: @eoinzy - `onResponse` is executed on the main thread: https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Callback.html "Callback methods are executed using the Retrofit callback executor. When none is specified, the following defaults are used: Android: Callbacks are executed on the application's main (UI) thread. [...]"

Comment: @eoinzy I have the same scenario. How you resolved this issue ?

Comment: @Menu As was said in the accepted answer, the `onResponse` callback is called in the Main Thread. My solution was to refactor my code. If I was to do it now, I'd be using Kotlin Coroutines and would use an async call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [JavaDoc](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/ResponseBody.html) of `ResponseBody` says:

> A one-shot stream from the origin server to the client application
>   with the raw bytes of the response body. **Each response body is
>   supported by an active connection to the webserver. This imposes both
>   obligations and limits on the client application.**

You see, your call of `bytes()` is using the still open connection to the webserver. This call is executed inside the `onResponse` callback and thus inside the main thread, which causes the `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Answer (score 0):

The request itself is executed in a background thread, yes. But the response callbacks, `onResponse` and `onFailure` are dispatched to and executed on the main thread.

Any work you do in there may not be network related or you will see the error you're having.

Comment: OK, but after `onResponse` returns, isn't the data downloaded into the `response` object, and I am just calling a "getter"? Or does calling body.bytes() invoke a network call? I find it strange if it invokes a network call after the response.

Comment: I do not know how your code works. But I am guessing that if leave empty the `onResponse` block, then it will not crash. I have the same code in my app and I don't use a background thread to handle the response and it works fine.